# Really slow OUTER JOIN on MariaDB compared to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, outer-join

### Context

Consider this table containing friends from a specific user.

```
CREATE TABLE `ce_mutual_friends`
(
    `user_id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL,
    `friend_id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `friend_id`),
    INDEX `friend_id_user_id` (`friend_id`, `user_id`)
   
)ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Please note that the list is mutual. If user 1 is befriended with friend 2 then this automatically means that user 2 is befriended with friend 1. There are 10K rows in this table.

### Objective

I want to have a list of users with:

- direct friends (relation_degree = 1 )
- friends of friends (relation_degree = 2 )
- friends of friends of friends (relation_degree = 3)

I do this by performing multiple LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
 -- for total network
WITH RECURSIVE cte(level, user_id, friend_id) AS(
  SELECT 1, user_id, friend_id
    FROM ce_mutual_friends
  UNION
  SELECT cte.level+1, cte.user_id, t2.friend_id
    FROM cte
      INNER JOIN ce_mutual_friends t2
        ON t2.user_id = cte.friend_id
    WHERE cte.level+1 <= 3 
)
SELECT cte.user_id, cte.friend_id, min(cte.level)
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY cte.user_id, cte.friend_id;
```

This query is runned several times a day to perform some background tasks.

### Problem

I was considering migrating from MySQL to MariaDB. On my development environment I use this `docker-compose.yml` to launch 2 containers.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql_db
    restart: always
    image: mysql:latest
    ports: 
        - "3306:3306" 
    environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports: 
        - "3305:3306" 
    environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I exported and imported my database from MySQL to MariaDB. I would expect that the query on MariaDB would be equal or slightly faster then on MySQL, but to my surprise MariaDB was far worst.

- MySQL 1.25sec
- MariaDB 26sec

If I modify the query to only fetch for one specific user (this query actually runs very often in our application ) then the duration's are:

- MySQL 0.002sec
- MariaDB 0.015sec

Here is the specific user adjusted query:

```
 -- for user 1
WITH RECURSIVE cte(level, user_id, friend_id) AS(
  SELECT 1, user_id, friend_id
    FROM ce_mutual_friends
    WHERE user_id = 1
  UNION
  SELECT cte.level+1, cte.user_id, t2.friend_id
    FROM cte
      INNER JOIN ce_mutual_friends t2
        ON t2.user_id = cte.friend_id
    WHERE cte.level+1 <= 3 
)
SELECT cte.user_id, cte.friend_id, min(cte.level)
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY cte.user_id, cte.friend_id;
```

**EXPLAIN SELECT ON MySQL**

```
+------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+-------------------+
|  id  |  select_type   |       table       | partitions | type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |      ref      |  rows  | filtered |          Extra           |                   |
+------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+-------------------+
| 1    | PRIMARY        | <derived2>        | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 131532 | 100.00   | "Using temporary"        |                   |
| 2    | DERIVED        | ce_mutual_friends | NULL       | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 6       | NULL          | 10506  | 100.00   | "Using index"            |                   |
| 3    | UNION          | cte               | NULL       | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | 10506  | 100.00   | "Recursive; Using where" |                   |
| 3    | UNION          | t2                | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 3       | cte.friend_id | 11     | 100.00   | "Using index"            |                   |
| NULL | "UNION RESULT" | "<union2          | 3>"        | NULL  | ALL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          | NULL   | NULL     | NULL                     | "Using temporary" |
+------+----------------+-------------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+-------------------+


+-------------------------------------+----------------+
|            Variable_name            |     Value      |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file     | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 1              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 134217728      |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25             |
| innodb_change_buffering             | all            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size              | 16777216       |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| key_buffer_size                     | 8388608        |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          |
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          |
| read_buffer_size                    | 131072         |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144         |
| select_into_buffer_size             | 131072         |
| sort_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| sql_buffer_result                   | OFF            |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

**EXPLAIN SELECT & Buffer varsON MariaBD**

```
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+--+
|  id  |    select_type    |       table       | type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |           ref           | rows  |               Extra               |  |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+--+
| 1    | PRIMARY           | <derived2>        | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                    | 10506 | "Using temporary; Using filesort" |  |
| 2    | DERIVED           | ce_mutual_friends | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 6       | NULL                    | 10506 | "Using index"                     |  |
| 3    | "RECURSIVE UNION" | t2                | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 6       | NULL                    | 10506 | "Using index"                     |  |
| 3    | "RECURSIVE UNION" | <derived2>        | ref   | key0          | key0    | 4       | mysite_prod_.t2.user_id | 10    | "Using where"                     |  |
| NULL | "UNION RESULT"    | "<union2          | 3>"   | ALL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                    | NULL  | NULL                              |  |
+------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+--+


+-------------------------------------+----------------+
|            Variable_name            |     Value      |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| aria_pagecache_buffer_size          | 134217728      |
| aria_sort_buffer_size               | 268434432      |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 8388608        |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 2147483648     |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25             |
| innodb_change_buffering             | all            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size              | 16777216       |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 262144         |
| join_buffer_space_limit             | 2097152        |
| key_buffer_size                     | 134217728      |
| mrr_buffer_size                     | 262144         |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 134216704      |
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          |
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          |
| read_buffer_size                    | 131072         |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144         |
| sort_buffer_size                    | 2097152        |
| sql_buffer_result                   | OFF            |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

1. I have tested these queries on MySQL Workbench. By my understanding this shouldn't make any difference. But please correct me if I am wrong.
2. How come that MariaDB so much slower then MySQL? Using `docker stats` and `htop` I see that there is no RAM shortage and 1 cpu core spikes for the duration of the query.

Comment: I'm curious if you would see the performance difference using `INNER JOIN` rather than `OUTER JOIN`.  The joins are effectively inner joins anyway, so this should not affect the results.

Comment: Both of the databases should run this really well.. Try analyzing the query on each database. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Smells to me like your MariaDB container is running out of RAM or otherwise malfunctioning. It hangs for 30sec and drops your connection. That's not "slow", that's really abnormal. If it were just slow it wouldn't drop the connection.

Comment: Follow the rules [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for indexing a many:many table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - `INNER` and `OUTER` are ignored.

Comment: For comparing MySQL and MariaDB, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...` for each.  It would be good to see if the query plans are different.

Comment: `ANALYZE TABLE ce_mutual_friends; ` Gives me status=ok on both database servers.

Comment: Do you see any difference in the output of `show variables like '%buffer%'`.

Comment: I have added the vars, I do not see any noticeable differences.

Comment: Well, you have 16x `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and 8x `sort_buffer_size` than MySQL; I wonder if there is enough RAM for that. Does it runs faster without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Hmm the RAM doesn't really run up when i am using this query. Mainly one of the CPU that is spiking. Removing the GROUP BY and min() is a little bit faster (-3s).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL >= 8.0.14 a [*Recursive Common Table Expression*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) should be more performant:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte(level, uid) AS(
  SELECT 1, friend_id
    FROM ce_mutual_friends
    WHERE user_id = 1
  UNION
  SELECT cte.level+1, friend_id
    FROM cte
      INNER JOIN ce_mutual_friends
        ON user_id = cte.uid
    WHERE cte.level+1 <= 3 
)
SELECT cte.uid, min(cte.level)
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY cte.uid;
```

Comment: The same will probably work in MariaDB-10.2+ too.

Comment: For the user specific query this takes about 0.015s, mine was 0.045s on MariaDB! I will try to study it more today and make one for the whole maintenance query.

Comment: Actual... after a close lookup I found out that the results are not the same. I have to place the `user_id = 1` in the select statement outside the CTE. Which is actually slower (>1s). For the network as a whole it is still faster. But still underperforming on Maria.